# XMLHttpRequest Request header field postman-token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, http, cors

I am attempting to access smartthings API in order to control devices locally. When I use the following chrome extension it DOES WORK, however I do not want to rely on something like this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en

I am getting the following error when I do not use the extension:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.smartthings.com/v1/devices/XXXX-
XXXX-XXXX/commands'from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by 
CORS policy: Request header field postman-token is not 
allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I have been trying to understand CORS and why I am being "denied" so to speak, but what I am confused about is that my response/request headers seem correct.
Here are the request and response headers:

```
GENERAL
Request URL: https://api.smartthings.com/v1/devices/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX/commands
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 204 No Content
Remote Address: 1x.xxx.1xx.xx:xxx
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

RESPONSE HEADERS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization,X-ST-Client,X-ST-Api-Version,X-ST-Client-AppVersion,X-ST-Client-OS,X-ST-Client-DeviceModel
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 06 Aug 2019 16:19:52 GMT
Server: openresty

REQUEST HEADERS
Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,cache-control,content-type,postman-token
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/compare/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/xxx.xx (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/xx.x.xxxx.xxx Safari/xxx.xx
```

My confusion with this is that the smartthings response seems to allow *, which to me makes me think I should not be receiving this error. However I am a little confused on how to edit/adjust these headers from my end, essentially I want to be doing whatever the chrome extension is doing? Here is how I am calling the smartthings API:

```
function APIAWAY(){

    var settings = {
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": "https://api.smartthings.com/v1/devices/XXX-XXXX/commands",
      "method": "POST",
      "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Bearer XXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Postman-Token": "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
      },
      "processData": false,
      "data": "{\r\n\"commands\": [\r\n{\r\n\"component\": \"main\",\r\n\"capability\": \"switch\",\r\n\"command\": \"on\"\r\n}\r\n]\r\n}"
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    });     
}
```

Comment: Use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) instead of "writing" your own JSON.

Comment: The reason why the request is blocked: _"Request header field `postman-token` is not allowed by `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in preflight response"_

Comment: @Andreas Thank you so much, such a simple solution! New to this type of development and appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Do this -

```
function APIAWAY(){
 var settings = {
          "async": true,
          "crossDomain": true,
          "url": "https://api.smartthings.com/v1/devices/XXX-XXXX/commands",
          "method": "POST",
          "headers": {
            "Authorization": "Bearer XXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "*/*",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "cache-control": "no-cache"
          },
          "processData": false,
          "data": "{\r\n\"commands\": [\r\n{\r\n\"component\": \"main\",\r\n\"capability\": \"switch\",\r\n\"command\": \"on\"\r\n}\r\n]\r\n}"
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        });     
    }
```

The problem is that you are adding `Postman-Token` header which is not accepted by the server.